# Horizontal list in document flow: how to set background color/border for just a few contiguous elements?

Tags: html, css, layout, nested-lists

Let's say I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<ul class="top-list">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li class="list-li">
        <ul class="inner-list">
            <li>I'm</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>sublist</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

I want the end result to look roughly like this:

[image]

In other words, I want the nested list to be in the exact same flow as the higher-level list, but with a colored background. Unfortunately, my CSS experiments so far have been futile. Neither `flexbox` nor `float` could handle breaking up the child list, and making the child list `inline` makes the parent collapse, causing the purple background to condense down to height 0.

Here's some CSS that comes very close, but having to specify odd pixel sizes just to get around `inline` layout issues is something I wish to avoid. Plus, if you shrink the page to where all three orange boxes are on their own line, there's still a sliver of purple background on the first line. I need to avoid this as well.

```
ul.inner-list {
    display: inline;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 3px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
li.list-li {
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.inner-list li {
    background-color: orange;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Frustratingly, having a non-nested list and simply surrounding the relevant elements with a `div` right in the `ul` seems to work perfectly for the same effect — but it's against the spec!

In other words, this is pretty close conceptually to what I want to do, but it's illegal:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <div>
        <li>I'm</li>
        <li>a</li>
        <li>sublist</li>
    </div>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did.  Hopefully you don't have to support old versions of IE, because I believe 7 doesn't support `inline-block`.

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jdczybvt/

HTML was the same:

```
<ul class="top-list">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li class="list-li">
        <ul class="inner-list">
            <li>I'm</li>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>sublist</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

CSS: I think all I added was the `display` for the outer `ul`.

```
ul.top-list{
   display:inline-block;
}

ul.inner-list {
    display: inline;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 3px;
    /*position: relative;*/
    bottom: 1px;
}
li.list-li {
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.inner-list li {
    background-color: orange;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
        display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I think that works mostly the same as the original. I really don't want to keep that padding and manual positioning around in the inner-list class, though — you can never get it perfect, especially around the edges. Plus, there's the dangling background problem I mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

OK, after experimenting a bit more, I have figured out two of my mistakes:

1. `inline-block` interprets newlines as whitespace. The HTML has to be compressed to get rid of glitches (including the errant background sliver described in the question).
2. Careless margins on the `li` elements will make calculating the padding on the `ul` difficult.

So with the following revised HTML:

```
<ul class="top-list"
    ><li>one</li
    ><li>two</li
    ><li>three</li
    ><li class="list-li"
        ><ul class="inner-list"
            ><li>I'm</li
            ><li>a</li
            ><li>sublist</li
        ></ul
    ></li
    ><li>four</li
    ><li>five</li
></ul>
<!-- fish! -->
```

And the following revised CSS:

```
ul.inner-list {
    display: inline;
    background-color: purple;
    white-space: none;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
li.list-li {
    display: inline;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
ul.inner-list li {
    background-color: orange;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/*line spacing*/
li {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

/*cell spacing*/
li:nth-child(1) {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
li {
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

...everything works much, much better. And it'll be better yet when I move some of those numbers to variables via SCSS. Nonetheless, if there's a solution that doesn't involve manually setting up the padding, I'd much rather use that. (Doesn't look like there is one at the moment, though.)